# Find top 3 students who have the highest total score across all subjects from the exam table in the database: Math_11a

Tags: mysql, sql

**INPUT** :
i have 3 tables students,Exams and Grades tables

```
**Students** table
+---------------+-------------------+
| Name          | description       |
+---------------+-----------+
| student_id    | student Id number |
| First_name    | student first name 
| Last_name     | student last name | 
+---------------+-------------------+

**Exams** Table:
+---------------+------------------+
|  Name         | description      |
+---------------+------------------+
| Name          | exam name        |
| Exam_ID       | exam identification |
| Date          | date of exam     |
+---------------+------------------+

**Grades** Table:
+---------------+------------------+
| Name          | description      |
+---------------+------------------+
| Student_ID    | student Id number|
| Exam_ID       | exam identification|
| grades        | score obtained   |
+---------------+------------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE Exams (
  ID BIGINT (20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  ,name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,exam_id INT (10) NOT NULL
  ,DATE DATE NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  );

INSERT INTO  Exams(name,exam_id,date) values ('mathematics',1,'2018-06-01'),('linear algebra',2,'2018-06-06'),('chemistry',3,'2018-06-11'),('physics',4,'2018-06-15'),('english language',5,'2018-06-20');

CREATE TABLE Graded (
  ID BIGINT (20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  ,student_ID INT (10) NOT NULL
  ,exam_id INT (10) NOT NULL
  ,grades INT (10) NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  );

INSERT INTO  Graded(student_ID,exam_id,grades) values  (1001,1,61), (1002,1,5), (1003,1,28), (1004,1,90), (1005,1,13), (1006,1,34), (1007,1,81), (1008,1,45), (1009,1,63), (1010,1,85), (1011,1,70), (1012,1,64), (1013,1,9), (1014,1,2), (1015,1,68), (1016,1,69), (1017,1,50), (1018,1,69), (1019,1,31), (1020,1,13), (1001,2,98), (1002,2,71), (1003,2,83), (1004,2,69), (1005,2,36), (1006,2,7), (1007,2,42), (1008,2,94), (1009,2,87), (1010,2,42), (1011,2,54), (1012,2,29), (1013,2,37), (1014,2,97), (1015,2,94), (1016,2,84), (1017,2,39), (1018,2,73), (1019,2,86), (1020,2,60), (1001,3,60), (1002,3,62), (1003,3,16), (1004,3,56), (1005,3,100), (1006,3,95), (1007,3,13), (1008,3,76), (1009,3,3), (1010,3,12), (1011,3,34), (1012,3,83), (1013,3,59), (1014,3,44), (1015,3,84), (1016,3,19), (1017,3,32), (1018,3,99), (1019,3,75), (1020,3,15), (1001,4,36), (1002,4,85), (1003,4,1), (1004,4,41), (1005,4,64), (1006,4,100), (1007,4,8), (1008,4,90), (1009,4,38), (1010,4,87), (1011,4,14), (1012,4,1), (1013,4,94), (1014,4,20), (1015,4,1), (1016,4,77), (1017,4,35), (1018,4,15), (1019,4,26), (1020,4,20), (1001,5,90), (1002,5,21), (1003,5,85), (1004,5,15), (1005,5,68), (1006,5,70), (1007,5,0), (1008,5,86), (1009,5,14), (1010,5,84), (1011,5,26), (1012,5,21), (1013,5,68), (1014,5,20), (1015,5,84), (1016,5,69), (1017,5,51), (1018,5,84), (1019,5,91), (1020,5,10);  

CREATE TABLE Students (
  ID BIGINT (20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  ,student_ID INT (10) NOT NULL
  ,first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
  ,last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  );

INSERT INTO  Students(student_ID,first_name,last_name) values (1001,'Dillon','Neitzel'), (1002,'Bridgette','Viruet'), (1003,'Lean','Wessel'), (1004,'Corey','Mogan'), (1005,'Amberly','Schneiderman'), (1006,'Pei','Mulhall'), (1007,'Sebrina','Nowicki'), (1008,'Anya','Ausherman'), (1009,'Laurice','Brannum'), (1010,'Fae','Southern'), (1011,'Alberto','Gilcrease'), (1012,'Keila','Wildt'), (1013,'Velvet','Wisneski'), (1014,'Gerard','Reinke'), (1015,'Awilda','enley'), (1016,'Leena','Hose'), (1017,'Myron','Karney'), (1018,'Collin','Wiles'), (1019,'Kiera','Benford'), (1020,'Hillary','Knaack');
```

**Output**: 
The top three students (both first name and last name) who have the highest total score across all the subjects.
The name should be in the format **'First name Last name'** eg. Tim Smith
The column name must be **"top_3_leaders"**

**Here's how I tried:**

```
 SELECT 
    CONCAT(students.first_name , " " , students.last_name) as Top_3_leaders, 
    (
        SELECT max(g.grades) FROM graded g 
        WHERE g.student_ID = Students.student_ID 
        AND g.exam_id = exams.exam_id
    ) AS total
FROM exams , students
ORDER BY total desc LIMIT 3;
```

**This's result I got**

```
 top_3_leaders          | total    |
 ----------------------------------|
 Amberly Schneiderman   | 100      |
 Pei Mulhall            | 100      |
 Collin Wiles           |  99      |
```

Instead of getting a total score of all subjects ,it's returning only for a single highest subject.
I was unable to return the right information. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: This is a help service. Not a free coding/sqling service. Formatting a readable question is a good first step too. This sort of query would be quite early in any SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, but if you could show what you have tried that would help more.

```
 SELECT first_name, last_name, MAX(score)
 FROM student_table
 INNER JOIN grade_table
 ON grade_table.student_id = student_table.student_id
 ORDER BY grade_table.score DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be answer the query, because to find top scorers across all subjects you have to sum grades per students and then order that sum in desc order and fetch top 3 results.

```
select concat(first_name," ",last_name) as "top_3_leaders"
        from Students 
               inner join 
             (select student_id, sum(grades) as total from grades
              group by student_id
              order by sum(grades) desc
              limit 3
              ) as t1
where students.student_id = t1.student_id
```